# Getting 502 (Bad Gateway) when uploading image to Cloudinary via API call

Tags: json, angular, typescript, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload image to Cloudinary via their rest api but i keep getting a 502 (Bad Gateway)  response. Please help!

I have tried searching for solutions online but could not find any that addresses the issue

The service that connects to Cloudinary API is as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageService {

  CLOUDINARY_URL = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxx/image/upload';
  CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET = 'xxxx';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  uploadImage(file: any):Observable<any> {
    console.log(file);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('upload_preset', this.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET);
    console.log("upload image in progress");
    return this.http.post<any>(this.CLOUDINARY_URL, formData, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

The function that reads user selected image file is as below:

```js
cloudFileChangeListener(event: any): void {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    this.isImageUploading = true;
    this.imageService.uploadImage(file).subscribe(response => {
      this.isImageUploading = false;
      console.log(response);
      this.imageUrl = response.secure_url;
    }, err => {
      this.isImageUploading = false;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
  }
```

Error returned is as below:

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":502,"statusText":"Bad Gateway","url":"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxxx/image/upload","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dexihbyv4/image/upload: 502 Bad Gateway","error":"<h2>Incomplete response received from application</h2>"}
```

N:B. The file is being uploaded locally.

Comment: Can you also post the 502 error that Cloudinary is returning? Is the file being uploaded locally or from a remote URL?

Comment: @DanielMendoza, i have updated my question with the error, kindly have a look.